# Xidel: How to process multiple result from one node?

Tags: bash, for-loop, xpath, xidel

Say, we have a code:

```
xidel -s https://www.example.com -e '(//span[@class="number"])'
```

and the output are:

```
111111
222222
333333
```

can I do this one below?

```
for ((n=1;n<=3;n++))
do
   a=$(xidel -s https://www.example.com -e '(//span[@class="number"]) [$n]')
   b=$a+1
   echo $b
done
```

I expect it to print out 3 edited numbers like this:

```
111112
222223
333334
```

it might be a little absurb to download the webpage 3 times, but the reason here is to process each value of the output one by one, using ForLoop.

Comment: You don't want a solution that downloads a whole webpage 8 times over just to print 8 different nodes. You want a solution that downloads the webpage *once* and selects 8 different nodes. The first thing you should do is get rid of the `for` loop.

Comment: yeah, thats what i thought too, but how to get around with the [number] thing, after the node?

Comment: How about `[position() <= 8]`

Comment: like this? `(//span[@class="number"]) [position() <= 8]`? the reason for me to use for loop is to process each output value, not just printing it.

Comment: *That's* your real question. *"How to process multiple result nodes from xidel?"* and even though I don't know xidel, I am quite sure that this is covered in the documentation.

Comment: okay, i change the title.

Comment: Also check out the documentation. This is such a common requirement that it's virtually impossible that this is not explained or shown.

Comment: @Tomalak done that, thanks for reply btw. I already have my own answer in the post, ultimately I use forLoop to solve.

Comment: Kudos for figuring something out that works, well done! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xidel` fully supports XPath/XQuery 3.0 (support for XPath/XQuery 3.1 is in development), so you can use all the features and filters it has to offer.
I can recommend the following websites:

- http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html
- https://github.com/benibela/xidel/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions
- https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/, https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/
- https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/
- http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_3.0
- http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/

---

Without a "[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" I'll just put your above mentioned output in a sequence and show you some examples.

```
xidel -se 'let $a:=(111111,222222,333333) return $a ! (. + 1)'
#or
xidel -se 'for $x in (111111,222222,333333) return $x + 1'
111112
222223
333334
```

```
xidel -se 'let $a:=("a abc","a sdf","a wef","a vda","a gdr") return $a ! substring-after(.,"a ")'
#or
xidel -se 'let $a:=("a abc","a sdf","a wef","a vda","a gdr") return $a ! replace(.,"a ","")'
#or
xidel -se 'for $x in ("a abc","a sdf","a wef","a vda","a gdr") return substring-after($x,"a ")'
#or
xidel -se 'for $x in ("a abc","a sdf","a wef","a vda","a gdr") return replace($x,"a ","")'
abc
sdf
wef
vda
gdr
```

Comment: thank you @Reino, for your brilliant answer. although, it seems that xidel `let` does not support `if else` statrment, it fully answered my post question.

Comment: @AhiungLim Please elaborate. If-statements shouldn't be a problem in a let-expression.

Comment: lets use this code below here:

`xidel -se '//div[@class="product-box"]//span[@class="n-heading"]' 'https://www.anekalogam.co.id/id'`

it should print 16 prices in Rupiah,
So what we should do is first remove the "Rp " and the ".", then for line 3 & 4, the value divide by 2, for line 5 & 6, the value divide by 3, and so on with these sequence (1,2,3,5,10,25,50,100), since line 1 & 2 is already in value of 1 so it does not need to be divided. After all that, we need to echo it side by side like 1 & 2, 3 & 4, etc.

like this for example:

`905000 - 825000
853000 - 825000
...`

Comment: @AhiungLim I see where you're going. This honestly is worth a new question if you ask me. But anyway, is this, https://gist.github.com/Reino17/2f166849a0ebe8c64a36613723ebac64, what you're looking for? Btw, please specify input before an (extraction-)query.

Comment: omg @Reino you are trully expert in xidel, arent you? I humbly gratitude for your excellent answer.

Comment: btw, @Reino, can you explain to me the expressions you used in the code? or I have to make new question about it?

Comment: @AhiungLim You're welcome. The real expert though is `xidel`'s author, Benito. I've learned a lot from him. I think it's better if you'd post a new question, yes. Alternatively you could also [subscribe to the mailinglist, or visit the forums](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html#contact). As the forums aren't particularly active, I'd recommend the mailinglist.

Answer (score 1):

Example code:

```
$ aa=$(xidel -se '//span[@class="random"]' 'https://www.example.com')
$ echo $aa
```

Lets say that the result of xidel is this below:

```
a abc
a sdf
a wef
a vda
a gdr
```

and...lets say we want to cut all the `a` from each word of this list in this case, not limiting to just excluding the `a`.

We can use `For Loop` formula like this:

```
#"a " is the one we want to remove, so make variable for this prefix
a="a "

for ((n=-1;n>=-5;n--))
do
 #process the extraction by selecting which line first
   bb=$(echo "$aa" | head $n | tail -1)
 #then remove the prefix after that
   bb=${aa/#$a}
   echo $bb

done
```

This will print:

```
abc
sdf
wef
vda
gdr
```

**Bonus**

```
#"a " is the one we want to remove, so make variable for this prefix
a="a "

for ((n=-1;n>=-5;n--))
do
 #process the extraction by selecting which line first
   bb=$(echo "$aa" | head $n | tail -1)
 #then remove the prefix after that
   bb=${aa/#$a}
 #echo everything except 2nd line
 if [ $n != -2 ] ; then
 echo $bb
 fi

done
```

This will print:

```
abc
wef
vda
gdr
```

Any other input is welcome